# how can I test fail error function with chai and mocha

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mocha.js, chai

Hello guys i'm newbie with testing 
I'm using socket.io and I want to simulate throwing error by my function when something happens on the insertion.

```
socket.on('request', function(request) {
  bookingService.addBooking(request)
  .then(function (booking) {
    winston.info('Client Order saved');
    io.emit('order to driver', {user: request[2], random : request[3]});
})
.catch(function (err) {
    winston.error(' Client error on save order ==> '+err);    
});

});
```

**addBooking**

```
function addBooking(msgParam) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    db.booking.insert(
        {   user    : msgParam[2],
            adress : msgParam[0],
            random  : msgParam[3],
            driver  : [],
            isTaken : false,
            isDone  : false,
            declineNbr : 0 ,
            createdOn  : msgParam[1],
            createdBy  : msgParam[2],
            updatedOn  : null,
            updatedBy  : []},
        function (err, doc) {
            if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);

            deferred.resolve();
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I tried to just test the addBokking function

```
it('should throw error if something wrong happend on adding new order ', function(done){
  (bookingService.addBooking(request)).should.throw()
  done();
});
```

but I get this error

```
 AssertionError: expected { state: 'pending' } to be a function
```

Comment: You should catch the error and then use assertion on that error.

Comment: Can you give some details plz @AbhyuditJain

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax with chai:

```
it("throw test", () => {
    expect(()=>{myMethodThatWillThrowError()}).to.throw();
});
```

For promises, you can use the following pattern:

```
it("should throw on unsuccessfull request", (done: MochaDone) => {
    repo.patch({
        idOrPath: "Root/Sites/Default_Site",
        content: ConstantContent.PORTAL_ROOT,
    }).then(() => {
        done("Should throw");  // The test will fail with the "Should throw" error
    }).catch(() => {
        done();                // The test will report success
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### You are checking the promise and not the result

This error:

> AssertionError: expected { state: 'pending' } to be a function

... means you are checking the promise returned from the `addBooking` function and not the resolved/rejected result of the promise.

With [chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised) you can do that easily!

With chai-as-promised these should work for example (from the documentation):

```
return promise.should.be.rejected;
return promise.should.be.rejectedWith(Error); // other variants of Chai's `throw` assertion work too.
```

or **in your specific case** (after installing and connecting [chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised)), this should work:

```
(bookingService.addBooking(request)).should.be.rejected
```

(maybe `should.throw()` will work with chai-as-promised too, I'm less familiar with it)

Check it out [here: chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised)